# Async function return before object with data built

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I'm not sure what's the best way to handle async / await here, it doesn't seem like my application is waiting before it calls render so it's trying to load before the data is ready.

**data.js:**

```
this.asyncFunction = async (x) => { return await _makeRestcall(x) }

this.load = async function(id) {
            this.data = {
                params: await asyncFunction("restCall1").value.reduce( // transform data),
                ideation: await asyncFunction("restCall2").value.reduce( // transform data),
                roles: await asyncFunction("restCall3").value.reduce( // transform data),
                serviceGroups: await asyncFunction("restCall4").value.reduce( // transform data),
                allocationPercents: [],
                maintenanceYears: [0, 3, 5]
            };

            return this.data;
        };

async init() {
    this.d = await this.load();
    console.log("called data async");
}
```

**app.js**

```
import data from 'data'
await data.init();
render()
```

Ideally I'd like all the calls in data to run in parallel then return this.data when all the calls are done.

Comment: `Promise.all` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a little test for you. I would recommend going with Promise.all, it can dispatch two async functions, but wait for them at the same place without blocking the function after each dispatch.

See the code below:

```
getFromAPIA();
getFromAPIB();

// A
async function getFromAPIA() {
    console.log('starting A');
    try {
        const [a, b] = await Promise.all([asyncFunction(), asyncFunction()])

        let data = {
            a,
            b,
        }
        console.log('A RES:', data);
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        return false; // Handle the error here in case the Promise returned a Reject
    }
}

// B
async function getFromAPIB() {
    console.log('starting B');
    try {
        let data = {
            a: await asyncFunction(),
            b: await asyncFunction(),
        }
        console.log('B RES:', data);
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        return false; // Handle the error here in case the Promise returned a Reject
    }
}

// MIMIC ASYNC
function asyncFunction() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res('Hello');
        }, 10000)
    })
};
```

Method B is basically what you did, which took double the time to get a response,
While Method A is with Promise.all. Now, promise all takes an array of promises as a parameter and also returns an array, so you will have to know the order of your dispatches in order to construct your object the way you want.

Comment: Would be nice if you could add an .then() and .catch() to the Promise.all(). Never let a Promise be uncatched and if he want to reuse your code i think it's better his errors would be caught.

Comment: I agree, promises should always be wrapped either in a try catch or handled with .then and .catch. I will edit it now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

*it doesn't seem like my application is waiting before it calls render so it's trying to load before the data is ready.*

you're waiting for the wrong object, you're waiting for Promise.value.reduce

```
this.asyncFunction = async (x) => { return await _makeRestcall(x) }

this.load = async function(id) {
    this.data = {
        params: (await asyncFunction("restCall1")).value.reduce( // transform data),
        ideation: (await asyncFunction("restCall2")).value.reduce( // transform data),
        roles: (await asyncFunction("restCall3")).value.reduce( // transform data),
        serviceGroups: (await asyncFunction("restCall4")).value.reduce( // transform data),
        allocationPercents: [],
        maintenanceYears: [0, 3, 5]
    };

    return this.data;
};

async init() {
    this.d = await this.load();
    console.log("called data async");
}
```